# Fetch dimensions, attributes and measures from Tabular Models of Cube in R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

So, I have been successful in establishing connection with a tabular model of a olap Cube. 
I can now successfully fetch dimensions also.
But I don't know how to fetch Attributes and Measures.

Here is the code I'm working on.

```
library(olapR)

conn_str1="Provider=MSOLAP; Data Source="Source Name "r;Persist Security Info=false;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

conn_obj1 <- OlapConnection(conn_str1)

# For fetching cube names in the data source
cube_list <- capture.output(explore(conn_obj1))
cube_list

# For fetching dimensions in the cube
dimensions <- capture.output(explore(conn_obj1,"Cube Name"))
dimensions
```

Comment: Once you have a dimension, you can call `explore` with parameter `dimension`. Then you may have hierarchy and/or directly levels and you would invoke again `explore` with feeding parameters `hiearchy` of `level` to have metadata on those levels.

Comment: how is this related to shiny and shiny-server?

Comment: I tagged it because I am actually trying to build a Shiny App. Just for wider reach.